# Reading a large CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have a very large CSV file. 51427 lines to be exact.

Is there not a way where I can only read the required lines into an array? That would speed things up significantly.

Comment: have you tried playing around with max execution time like `ini_set("max_execution_time", 0)` ?

Comment: A couple questions:
- How are you importing the file into the database?
- Do you upload the file before importing or do you read it real-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at streaming the csv file. Send start file location, start position and number of bytes to read as get paramters to a ProgressiveReader.php

```
class NoFileFoundException extends Exception {
    function __toString() {
        return '<h1><b>ERROR:</b> could not find ('
                    .$this->getMessage().
                    ') please check your settings.</h1>';
    }
}

class NoFileOpenException extends Exception {
    function __toString() {
        return '<h1><b>ERROR:</b> could not open ('
                    .$this->getMessage().
                    ') please check your settings.</h1>';
    }
}

interface Reader {
    function setFileName($fName);
    function open();
    function setBufferOffset($offset);
    function bufferSize();
    function isOffset();
    function setPacketSize($size);
    function read();
    function isEOF();
    function close();
    function readAll();
}

class ProgressiveReader implements Reader {
    private $fName;
    private $fileHandler;
    private $offset = 0;
    private $packetSize = 0;

    public function setFileName($fName) {
        $this->fName = $fName;
        if(!file_exists($this->fName)) {
            throw new NoFileFoundException($this->fName);
        }
    }

    public function open() {
        try {
            $this->fileHandler = fopen($this->fName, 'rb');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new NoFileOpenException($this->fName);
        }
        fseek($this->fileHandler, $this->offset);
    }

    public function setBufferOffset($offset) {
        $this->offset = $offset;
    }

    public function bufferSize() {
        return filesize($this->fName) - (($this->offset > 0) ? ($this->offset  + 1) : 0);
    }

    public function isOffset() {
        if($this->offset === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function setPacketSize($size) {
        $this->packetSize = $size;
    }

    public function read() {
        return fread($this->fileHandler, $this->packetSize);
    }

    public function isEOF() {
        return feof($this->fileHandler);
    }

    public function close() {
        if($this->fileHandler) {
            fclose($this->fileHandler);
        }
    }

    public function readAll() {
        return fread($this->fileHandler, filesize($this->fName));
    }
}
```

Here are the unit tests:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../ProgressiveReader.php';

class ProgressiveReaderTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $reader;
    private $fp;
    private $fname = "Test.txt";

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->createTestFile();
        $this->reader = new ProgressiveReader();
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        $this->reader->close();
    }

    public function test_isValidFile() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
    }

    public function test_isNotValidFile() {
        try {
            $this->reader->setFileName("nothing.tada");
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return;
        }

        $this->fail();
    }

    public function test_isFileOpen() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->open();
    }

    public function test_couldNotOpenFile() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        try {
            $this->deleteTestFile();
            $this->reader->open();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return;
        }

        $this->fail();
    }

    public function test_bufferSizeZeroOffset() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->bufferSize(), 12);
    }

    public function test_bufferSizeTwoOffset() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(2);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->bufferSize(), 9);
    }

    public function test_readBuffer() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(0);
        $this->reader->setPacketSize(1);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->read(), "T");
    }

    public function test_readBufferWithOffset() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(2);
        $this->reader->setPacketSize(1);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->read(), "S");
    }

    public function test_readSuccesive() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(0);
        $this->reader->setPacketSize(6);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->read(), "TEST1\n");
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->read(), "TEST2\n");
    }

    public function test_readEntireBuffer() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertEquals($this->reader->readAll(), "TEST1\nTEST2\n");
    }

    public function test_isNotEOF() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(2);
        $this->reader->setPacketSize(1);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->assertFalse($this->reader->isEOF());
    }

    public function test_isEOF() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(0);
        $this->reader->setPacketSize(15);
        $this->reader->open();
        $this->reader->read();
        $this->assertTrue($this->reader->isEOF());
    }

    public function test_isOffset() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->reader->setBufferOffset(2);
        $this->assertTrue($this->reader->isOffset());
    }

    public function test_isNotOffset() {
        $this->reader->setFileName($this->fname);
        $this->assertFalse($this->reader->isOffset());
    }

    private function createTestFile() {
        $this->fp = fopen($this->fname, "wb");
        fwrite($this->fp, "TEST1\n");
        fwrite($this->fp, "TEST2\n");
        flush();
        fclose($this->fp);
    }

    private function deleteTestFile() {
        if(file_exists($this->fname)) {
            unlink($this->fname);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Lotsa code for what is likely a one time (or rare) import process.  
Upload csv and use mysql console to load the data.

Comment: Yep your right, except he doesn't want to wait for the entire file to upload then store *'I am not happy having to reach the entire 51427 lines of the CSV file into an array before processing'*. Also there is some tests on the code. Oh and one person's **one time** is another duplicated effort until you get pissed off and automate it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you connect to the database server directly?

If so, I would consider using a 3rd party program like SQLyog to import your csv.

You could also upload the file and use the mysql shell to import that data directly:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your_file.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Answer (score 2):

> This reads the entire CSV file into an array

All of the 50000+ lines?

Advance to the start of the wanted block of the file from PHP by reading line by line (fgets()) and then add each (needed) line to the array; you can get the array of the line with fgetcsv().

edit: I don't know the exact details, but I sense that reading everything into a data structure costs way more than reading only what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Your script probably takes too long and it gets terminated.

You should look for `max_execution_time` directive in `php.ini` and set it to something that suits you.

The default `max_execution_time` is set to 30 seconds, so your script probably gets terminated.

If you also have scripts that need to be limited in time, you can do that individually by calling `set_time_init();`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using bash/shell(if you're on linux) to import your csv into mysql? You can also use ruby or perl or whatnot, as I think that's what you should use instead of php(or any web app) to import the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the fast MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE command:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

If that's not an option, you could split the CSV file (assuming access to a shell).

Answer (score 0):

Bah! Ignore this answer.  Was a duplicate.  See  Scorchio's mention of fgetcsv() above.